# Metric completeness of continuous bounded functions targeting a complete metric space

Tags: functional-analysis, complete-spaces

### The problem

Let $CBT(X,Y)$ be the set of continuous, bounded functions that map topological space $(X, \tau)$ to a complete metric space $(Y, \rho)$. Define  a metric on $CBT$ as follows: $\rho_\infty(f, g) := \underset{x \in X}{\sup}\rho(f(x), g(x))$.

It is needed to prove that $(CBT(X, Y),\ \rho_\infty)$ is a complete metric space.

### My ideas

I am quite sure I've seen something similar before, but not this abstract. It is probably the fact that topology $\tau$ can be arbitrary that is confusing me.

Having a fundamental sequence of functions from $CBT$ it is not difficult to prove it converges pointwise. I would define the *presumed* limit function $f$ as $f(x) := \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}f_n(x)$.

Now I believe I need to prove $\{f_n\}$ converges to $f$ in $\rho_\infty$, and that $f$ is itself continuous and bounded.

I am interested what is the usual way to prove this kind of things and whether my idea could work?